# INSERT a RANK into a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, dense-rank

I have a table that has the following columns:

```
NAME (VARCHAR) 
FISHING (INT) 
SAILING (INT) 
NAVIGATION (INT) 
SALARY (NUMERIC)
```

This table has 9 rows of data. I used `ALTER` to add a column that would hold the `rank` of the person's salary. It is called `SALARY_RANK`. My idea was to populate that column with a `SELECT` statement that would fill that rank. I tried to use `INSERT` with the below `SELECT` statement to fill that column but it ends up creating 9 new rows where all except the new column are `NULL`.

What is the best way to go about this?

This is the SQL I have written for the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE #CODY_CREW 
ADD  SALARY_RANK INT;

INSERT INTO #CODY_CREW (SALARY_RANK)
    SELECT 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY) AS 'SALARY_RANK'
    FROM #CODY_CREW
```

This is what happens when I run that:

```
NAME                                               FISHING     SAILING     NAVIGATION  SALARY                                  SALARY_RANK
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------- -----------
Amy                                                3           5           1           46000                                   NULL
Bill                                               1           2           5           43000                                   NULL
Carl                                               3           4           2           47000                                   NULL
Dan                                                4           3           1           36000                                   NULL
Eva                                                4           2           2           43000                                   NULL
Fred                                               1           3           4           55000                                   NULL
Greg                                               3           1           5           68000                                   NULL
Henry                                              5           4           2           64000                                   NULL
Ida                                                3           3           3           60000                                   NULL
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    1
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    2
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    2
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    3
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    4
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    5
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    6
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    7
NULL                                               NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL                                    8

(18 rows affected)
```

Comment: There is UPDATE in sql that update the existing record

Comment: This table design seems weird to me. Specifically, what happens if, for example, Amy gets a 10k raise. The salary_rank column will have to be updated not only for her but for several other employees as well. What is your plan to keep this up to date? Redo the dense_rank query and update anybody that doesn't match?

Comment: agreed - this is a workplace trivia type thing we do for fun - its not a real data set - I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` query. Try like below.

```
UPDATE C1
SET C1.SALARY_RANK = C2.SALARY_RANK
FROM #CODY_CREW C1
JOIN (SELECT 
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY) AS 'SALARY_RANK', Name
FROM #CODY_CREW) C2
ON C1.Name = C2.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE or subquery:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT cc.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY) AS NEW_SALARY_RANK
      FROM #CODY_CREW cc
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET SALARY_RANK = NEW_SALARY_RANK;
```

A `JOIN` is not necessary.